# Crawl non-latin domain with scrapy

Tags: python, url, httprequest, scrapy

I need to crawl some websites in ".рф" domain zone with scrapy. Url has structure like this: "[http://сайтдляпримера.рф](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84)" (this url is not real, it's given for example). Of course website I try to work with is accessible with browser.
I tried to use the `start_urls` property to begin with crawling, eg.:

```
start_urls = ['http://сайтдляпримера.рф']
```

And also `start_requests` function:

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [scrapy.Request("http://сайтдляпримера.рф/", callback=self._test)]
```

Neither of them worked as expected, I got following console message:

```
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84> (failed 1 times): DNS lookup failed: address '%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84' not found: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: address '%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84' not found: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84> (failed 3 times): DNS lookup failed: address '%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84' not found: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84>: DNS lookup failed: address '%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0.%D1%80%D1%84' not found: [Errno -2] Name or service not known.
2016-01-01 19:02:01 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

*If it is matters, I need to use scrapy on Linux-based OS.

Are there any solutions? If possible is there a way I can solve this from the `_spider` file due to I don't have access to framework's repository (nothing that handles http requests was modified there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with Internationalized Domain Names (IDN) you need to encode non-ascii urls with `idna`. You will need to decode resulting bytes into a unicode string then. Also note that an ascii substring of your url making up a protocol name ('http://') should be prefixed separately, so that you are not messing up when doing `idna` encoding:

```
'http://' + u'сайтдляпримера.рф'.encode('idna').decode('utf-8')
```

See also [this document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.idna) for more details.

Comment: got an error `exceptions.TypeError: must be unicode, not str`, when I try to do something like `"http://сайтдляпримера.рф".decode('utf-8').encode('idna')` then I get `xn--http://-8fga3bl9al3aq0crdjw9y.xn--p1ai` and `NotSupported: Unsupported URL scheme 'xn--http': no handler available for that scheme`

Comment: @Helvdan try it other way around: `'http://сайтдляпримера.рф'.encode('idna').decode('utf-8')`. That will conver bytes into unicode string

Comment: it is the same error `xceptions.TypeError: must be unicode, not str` because `'somestr'.method1().method2()` is a chain call. So there is no difference with your original answer.

Comment: @Helvdan okay, it seems that the problem is caused by encoding of the latin prefix of your url. Try this: `'http://' + 'сайтдляпримера.рф'.encode('idna').decode('utf-8')`. Just tried it myself with `urlopen` and it worked. Hopefully it will also work for `scrapy`

Comment: you are lifesaver. This has worked. Can you modify your answer to match your last comment?

Comment: due to scrapy works with python 2.7 only, it is required to unicode string first like `'http://' + u'сайтдляпримера.рф'.encode('idna')`. I bet you tested your example on python 3x.